# How to get array from nested array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

How to get nested array

```
 const array = arrayResult.map((loc) => loc.someOptions.map(options => {return options.someOptions}));

console.log(array);
```

I need to get array from nested array,

```
if (array.flat().includes('two')) {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

actual output :

Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'.

expected output :
['one','two']
"hello"

Comment: can you please update the question with input data and expected output.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOzlrW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your array using `array#flat()` and then check for `two` in your array.

```js
const array = [ ['one'], ['two']];

if (array.flat().includes('two')) {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Comment: Error : Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'.

Comment: You should add `es2019` or `es2019.array` to your `--lib` setting for TypeScript to recognize `array.flat()`.

Comment: Hm, how to do it, using typescript instruments? without editing config file

Comment: If you don't want to  update your ts config, then try with `[].concat(...array).includes('two');` instead of `array.flat().includes('two')`

Comment: after that ,output : [ [ 'one' ], [ 'two' ], [ 'one' ], [ 'two' ]

Comment: Can you share `console.log(array)` and `console.log([].concat(...array))`. Feels like your output is different.